# How can I increase TX-Power on Intel AX200 card?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

### The Problem

I have an Intel AX200 card, connected to my PCI-E slot. I want to increase the tx-power from 22dBm (default) to 24-25 (all for 5Ghz).

### What I tried

I tried following this [guide](https://miloserdov.org/?p=337) but both methods didn't work. I changed the txpower in the CRDA files to 30 both in my country, the US and 00, but when I try to run:

```
sudo iw dev wlp8s0 set txpower fixed 30mBm
```

Or:

```
sudo iw dev wlp8s0 set txpower fixed 3000
```

It doesn't work and iwconfig still shows TX-Power: 22dBm. If I try to lower it and run:

```
sudo iw dev wlp8s0 set txpower fixed 2000
```

It changes to 20dBm.

When I run

```
iw reg get
```

It used to print the global profile as well as a different list for the iwlwifi driver so the card was managed but I edited the /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf file and edded:

```
options iwlwifi lar_disable=1
```

And after restarting the card it shows just the global profile, so it should use the global CRDA files I made using the guide. It's the same when I change my regulatory domain to US, BO, BZ, my country (instead of 00) and when I remove the lar_disable=1.

### Info

The card itself was bought from an American store so if anything it should be hardcoded to US regulation with allow up to 30dBm (or at least 23, rather than 22).
Ubuntu 20.04.

#### iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp8s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"***"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: ***   
          Bit Rate=585.1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:35   Missed beacon:0

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

#### iw reg get:

```
global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 30), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 30), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 30), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)
```

#### lspci -v:

```
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Memory at fc900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Is there any way of getting around it? Maybe editing the iwlwifi files directly?

Comment: Hi @ronk56 , did you figure out how to increase power. I have the same problem and cannot find any solution yet.